# Dynamically changing the tooltip of a draw2d figure

Tags: java, eclipse

We are currently using Eclipse Draw2D/GEF for an information page describing a process in our application. This basically consists of a matrix of large squares, each containing a matrix of smaller squares. We originally had all the squares as GEF objects, but because of the large volume of them being shown, we found that this did not scale very well and the view took a very long time to open. We then changed it so that only the large squares are Figures and we then draw the smaller squares using the graphic in paintFigure.

The problem that we are running into is that we still want the tooltip to change depending on which small square you are hovering over. I tried to do this by adding a mouseMotionListener and setting the tooltip, through setTooltip, depending on where the mouse currently is. The problem is that once the tooltip is displayed, it does not change any more when setTooltip is called.

Does any one know of an alternative way of doing this? Is there a way of getting the viewpart's PopupHelper and using that? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmnn.. interesting problem.  Since you paint your own Grid within the Figure, I would think that you have two options.

1. Try posting SWT events to fool Eclipse.  I'd try a focus lost followed by a focused gained, to trigger tooltip machinery, at which point you could get the coordinates and display the appropriate contents.
2. Don't use the Figure#getTooltip strategy at all.  Just show your own composite.

Comment: Thanks, did not think of posting SWT events. Good idea though. I have, in the mean time, implemented option 2, which works good enough.

Comment: If that worked for you can you mark this as a correct answer?  It gives points - thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically change the tooltip, you can hold an instance of the tooltip Figure in your parent Figure. In the constructor of the parent Figure, create a new tooltip Figure (e.g. a Label) and use setToolTip() method to set the tooltip Figure to parent Figure.

When data model is changed, the updated tooltip text/icon can be set to the tooltip Figure. Then you just call setToolTip(tooltipFigure) method again.

You can have a method like:

> protected Label toolTipLabel;
>
> protected void updateToolTip(String text, Image icon){
> toolTipLabel.setText(text);
> toolTipLabel.setIcon(icon);
> setToolTip(toolTipLabel);
> }

The updateToolTip() method can be invoked in parent Figure's conturctor to initialize the tooltip. And this method can be invoked each time after the data model is changed.

I encountered the same problem in my code and solved it with that method. In my code, I invoked the updateToolTip() in the parentFigure.paintFigure() method.